# Python doesn't read in the correct number of columns

Tags: python, numpy, load

I am trying to read in a txt file with 2 columns (first one string, second one double, tab seperated).

This is my datafile:

```
C#  6.78
D   5.32
W   5.32
-> data.txt
```

This is my reduced code:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('data.txt',delimiter='\t', dtype=str)

print data
```

It gives me the following error:

```
 File "loader.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt('data.txt',delimiter='\t', dtype=str)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 853, in loadtxt
    % line_num)
ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2
```

I don't understand this, because there are an equal amount of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably due to the `#` in your file, which is interpreted as a comment (see [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)).  Try passing `comments=None` to `loadtxt`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the `#` in the first line.  It is interpreted as a comment character.  Thus the first line has 1 field, so it expects the 2nd to be the same.  Either remove the character, or change the 'comment' parameter of `loadtxt` to something else.